# Could not find or load main class com.ibm.broker.config.util.PackageBarGenRtObjWrapper

Tags: jenkins, build, automation, ant, ibm-integration-bus

I am running a ANT job. Build.xml is working fine in local command prompt but the same job is not working in Jenkins and getting below exception.

Error: Could not find or load main class com.ibm.broker.config.util.PackageBarGenRtObjWrapper

Please someone can help me out. Let me know if you need further details.

Comment: I'm not an ANT expert, but this sounds like a classpath issue. Have you checked that?

Comment: Can you show us your build.xml? And your IIB relevant environment before you invoke ant (`set MQS` on Windows or `printenv | grep MQS` on Unix)?

Comment: Hi Daniel, Thanks for the comments. Please find the env variables
C:\Users\gopin>set mqs
MQSIJAVA=C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre1.8.0_311\lib\
MQSI_BASE_FILEPATH=C:\Program Files\IBM\ACE\11.0.0.11
MQSI_JREPATH=C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre1.8.0_311\lib;

Comment: It is better to edit and incorporate the new information into your question,  it can be formatted by adding ``` above and below the content.